# Missing DataContractJsonSerializer from mono touch new update

Tags: json, xamarin.ios, datacontractserializer

I updates Monotouch and now I'm missing the DataContractJsonSerializer from the json dll.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace for the DataContractJsonSerializer in Xamarin.IOS is:

System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer

Comment: I'm using xamarine version 4.0.10 and System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer
doesn't exist.

Comment: What is your License level, and Wow.. that's a bit back there in age, yes?